# TSQL - GROUP BY on continous rows only

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-server-2017

I am working on a SQL Server 2017 (v14.0).

I have a table like this:

```
Key | State    | from       | until      |
----+----------+------------+------------+
100 | open     | 01.01.2021 | 01.01.2021 |
100 | open     | 02.01.2021 | 02.01.2021 |
100 | closed   | 03.01.2021 | 13.01.2021 |
100 | open     | 14.01.2021 | 20.01.2021 |
100 | open     | 20.01.2021 | 30.01.2021 |
```

I want to group it by `Key` and `State`, but only for continuous rows.

So my expected result would be something like:

```
Key | State    | from       | until      |
----+----------+------------+------------+
100 | open     | 01.01.2021 | 02.01.2021 |
100 | closed   | 03.01.2021 | 13.01.2021 |
100 | open     | 14.01.2021 | 30.01.2021 |
```

Any idea on how to do this? I have the strong feeling, that this should be possible with the help of `ROW_NUMBER` somehow, but I was not able to figure it out yet...

*(In this example data some weird `group by calendarweek` or something similar might be possible, but this is not my intention)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a  Gaps and Islands problem. One solution is this:

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN LAG([state]) OVER (PARTITION BY [key] ORDER BY [from]) = [state] THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS chg
    FROM t
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(chg) OVER (PARTITION BY [key] ORDER BY [from]) AS grp
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT [key], grp, MIN([state]), MIN([from]), MAX([until])
FROM cte2
GROUP BY [key], grp
ORDER BY [key], grp
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is as below added:

```
Create table myTable_o1
 (
 [key] int
 ,[state] varchar(100)
 ,[From] date
 ,[Until] date
 )

insert into myTable_o1 values (100, 'open', '2021-01-01','2021-01-01')
insert into myTable_o1 values (100, 'open', '2021-01-02','2021-01-02')
insert into myTable_o1 values (100, 'closed', '2021-01-03','2021-01-13')
insert into myTable_o1 values (100, 'open', '2021-01-4','2021-01-20')
insert into myTable_o1 values (100, 'open', '2021-01-20','2021-01-30')

SELECT 
   [key] 
   ,[state] 
   ,[From] 
   ,[until] 
FROM
(
Select 
  [key] 
 , [state] 
 , [From] 
 , row_number() over (partition by tiles order by [key]) row_num
 , ISNULL(Lead(Until) over (partition by tiles order by [key]) , Until) [until]
 FROM
 (
    SELECT * ,
    Ntile(2) over ( order by [Key]) as [tiles]
    from myTable_o1
   ) AS A
 ) AS B WHERE B.row_num in (1,3)
```

[image: Result]